# Simulating crosstalk and reflection waves using the same lumped RLCG circuit in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, transmission-line, crosstalk

Is it possible to add line delay to an RLCG type circuit? Using this type of circuit, I'm able to simulate capacitive and inductive coupling, but no reflection waves. Using a SPICE tline, however, reflection can be simulated but I guess no crosstalk. Is it possible to combine these two?

Answer (score 2):

If you're only relying on a single RLCG cell then you will disappointed. There will be some sort of delay, but not the expected one. Using several cells will get you a delay, but you will need to carefully tune the value of each element if you want a smooth response. You can use the matrix notation for simplification, but then all the values will be the same and the result will be oscillating. But there will be a delay and reflections, therefore you can have everything on one plate:

[image: test]

Answer (score 2):

An original Berkeley SPICE (after ver. 3f5) has a number of academic continuations specialized for application areas. Among these, [KSPICE (based on ver. 3e2)](https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/projects/embedded/pubs/downloads/spice/) features improved transient analysis of lossy transmission lines based on Pade approximation of the transfer function.

LTspice has [two KSPICE-originated RLCG-type lossy transmission line models](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice#Lossy_Transmission_Lines), only hidden in undocumented features:

> **Lossy Transmission Lines**
>
> There are two undocumented lossy transmission line models implemented
> in LTspice.  One is CPL model (P device), and the other is TXL model
> (Y device).
>
> The undocumented CPL is a K-Spice-like element, which in theory should
> be similar to the RLGC model, but without frequency dependent loss
> (neither skin effect and nor frequency dependent dielectric loss).  It
> also has at least one bug causing an incorrect output voltage offset
> (a workaround is to only use signals with no dc offset).

The netlist that follows in this reference is seemingly taken from a real-life IC development project. I simplified the referenced circuit (removed signal-generating transistor amplifiers M1-M6 unnecessary for demonstration of CPL model working), and you can easily verify, varying the CPL model parameters, that both reflection and crosstalk (and signal damping by conduction and resistance losses) are present in a transient analysis simulation plot. The symbol ***U1 cpltline*** is generated with a subcircuit given in the comment text of this drawing.

[image: CPLtline]

Working of parameters of the Pline CPL model can be inferred by examining references of the UBerkeley Ptolemy project documentation or from examples with the [KSPICE package distro](https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/projects/embedded/pubs/downloads/spice/kspice.tar.Z).

The netlist extracted from the circuit above directly uses the Pline CPL model without the agency of subckt that is only required for symbol generation:

```
* RLCG simulation with Pline CPL model
Co1 out1 0 9f4
Co2 out2 0 9f4
P1 in1 in2 0 out1 out2 0 Pline
Vs1 in1 0 PULSE(0 5 15n9 0n2 0n2 15n8 10000n)
Vs2 in2 0 PULSE(0 5 16n9 0n2 0n2 15n8 10000n)
.tran 0n2 200n 0 1n
.model Pline CPL
+ R=0.2 0 0.2
+ L=9n13 3n3 9n13
+ G=0.0002 0 0.0002
+ C=365f -90f 365f
+ Length=72
.backanno
.end
```

Comment: It's true that they exist and they also work (though there may be some hiccups every now and then), but using a transmission line doesn't allow for inductive or capacitive coupling. Maybe I misread OP's request?

Comment: No personal allergies, but there is one in the quote you used: "*It also has at least one bug ...*". I also recall simulations going very slow, even for basic test rigs, but it's also true I haven't touched these in a long while. I see veterans that deal with cables and use RLC ladders, instead; they might have a reason. At any rate, it's up to OP to decide. BTW, in your simulation `Ci1` and `Ci2` do not contribute with anything, unless there is a hidden `Rser` in the source, unseen in the schematic, because in the netlist there is none.